# Best Practice for Self-updating Package?

Tags: package-management, updates

I am building a Linux package for an application I have developed. I have it checking for updates when it starts, and installing updates via triggering `sudo apt-get install <package>`, which of course prompts the user for permission.

What is the best practice/appropriate way to go about doing this? Is my current methodology common or ideal? If not, what should I do?

I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me; I just want to be pointed in the right direction so that my app follows expected behaviour. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is your package hosted in a repository, or do you just provide a deb file?

Comment: @muru It is hosted in a repository. A local one for testing, but intended for a hosted one if I follow this route.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a public repository, like a PPA, and rely on the package manager to find out about and install updates instead of doing that from within your program:

- To make your update being able to be installed via `apt-get` you need to run `apt-get update` first to load the updated package information. This can take quite some time and cause a lot of network traffic.
- A normal user may not be able to use any `apt-get` command at all.
- Your `apt-get`calls may get blocked because another process is accessing the package manager, or it may block other processes from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a repository, you can probably depend on [`unattended-upgrades`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) and add a configuration file to automatically download and install upgrades from your repository. For example, a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` named `60my-repo-upgrade`, containing:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "<origin>:<archive>";
};
```

Where `<origin>` and `<archive>` are from the `Release` file of your repository. can be obtained from the output of `apt-cache policy`. For example, Google Chrome's repository has `<origin>` as `Google, Inc.` and `<archive>` as `stable`:

```
$ apt-cache policy | grep -i google
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
```

That way, the user can modify the configuration if they need to, and decide a schedule for `unattended-upgrades`.